# i want to show linearlayout visible/gone when i click on the button

Tags: android

I want to show layout based on user click on the button intially i kept in gone position when user click on button i need to visible for particular position only,but my problem is when start to visible or gone to the view based user click on button the layout is visible for all position,how to show linerlauout is visble to only user clcking positions.

```
private String[] mOptinItems = new String[] { "achsdsgdddddddddddddd",
        "achsdsgdddddddddddddd" };

private String[] dateArray = new String[] { "22nd jun 1012",
        "22nd jun 1012" };
int[] myImageList = new int[] { R.drawable.img, R.drawable.img };

private boolean btnMoreStatus = false;;

private ListView mEvents_Lsit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventlist);

    initViews();
    CustomMovieListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomMovieListViewAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.event_item);

    mEvents_Lsit.setAdapter(adapter);
    // addItemsToLL();

}

private void initViews() {

    mEvents_Lsit = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settings_list_ll);

}

/**
 * This Adapter is used forto the set items to movie item list.
 * 
 * @author imaddikunta
 * 
 */
public class CustomMovieListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    ViewHolder holder;

    public CustomMovieListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView eventImageView;
        TextView tTitle;
        TextView date;
        TextView eventTitle;
        TextView eventText;
        Button showText;
        LinearLayout llShowText;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        holder = null;

        // final MovieItemBean movie = mMovieItemsList.get(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvTittle);
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            holder.eventImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.event_img_view);

            holder.llShowText = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lleventDisplay);
            holder.showText = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.showText);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.tTitle.setText(mOptinItems[position]);
        holder.date.setText(dateArray[position]);
        holder.eventImageView.setImageResource(myImageList[position]);

        if (btnMoreStatus) {
            holder.llShowText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.llShowText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.showText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (holder.llShowText.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

                    holder.llShowText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnMoreStatus = true;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {

                    btnMoreStatus = false;
                    holder.llShowText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mOptinItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
enter code here
```

Comment: 'notifyDataSetChanged()' refreshes complete `listview` so that time UI correction occurs for your entire `listview`. Try to add position too. Do like this, `if (btnMoreStatus && pos){}`, within your `showText.onclick()' try to do this `pos = position`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listData;
    private ListView mEvents_Lsit;
    private CustomMovieListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mEvents_Lsit = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settings_list_ll);
        prePareListData();
        adapter = new CustomMovieListViewAdapter(this,listData);
        mEvents_Lsit.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void prePareListData(){
        listData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String,Object> row1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row1.put("name","Android1");
        row1.put("date","22nd jun 1012");
        row1.put("image",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        row1.put("isSelected",false);
        listData.add(row1);
        HashMap<String,Object> row2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row2.put("name","Android2");
        row2.put("date","23nd jun 1012");
        row2.put("image",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        row2.put("isSelected",false);
        listData.add(row2);
        HashMap<String,Object> row3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row3.put("name","Android3");
        row3.put("date","24nd jun 1012");
        row3.put("image",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        row3.put("isSelected",false);
        listData.add(row3);
    }

    public class CustomMovieListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listData;

        public CustomMovieListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listData) {
            this.listData=listData;
            this.context = context;

        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView eventImageView;
            TextView tTitle;
            TextView date;
            TextView eventTitle;
            TextView eventText;
            Button showText;
            LinearLayout llShowText;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.event_item, null);
                holder.tTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTittle);
                holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
                holder.eventImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_img_view);
                holder.llShowText = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lleventDisplay);
                holder.showText = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.showText);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            holder.tTitle.setText((String)listData.get(position).get("name"));
            holder.date.setText((String)listData.get(position).get("date"));
            holder.eventImageView.setImageResource((Integer)listData.get(position).get("image"));

            if ((Boolean)listData.get(position).get("isSelected")) {
                holder.llShowText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.llShowText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.showText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if ((Boolean)listData.get(position).get("isSelected")) {
                        listData.get(position).put("isSelected", false);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        listData.get(position).put("isSelected", true);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return listData.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ListViewAdapter you need to delete list of item from which build your list View

So you need to delete items from mOptinItems, dateArray, myImageList

then set notifyDataSetChanged

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter());
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
});
```